# Form not submitted when multiple property names are similar in View model - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am just curious to understand the various ways, how the model values are posted to controller from view.

In this process, I was trying to do the below and submit didn't work.

```
//Model:

class Employee
{
     string Name {get;set;}
     string name {get;set;}
     string Gender { get; set; }
}

//View:

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <span>Name</span> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
}

//Controller:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Employee e, string Name)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
    else
    return View(e);

}
```

When I clicked on Submit, it didn't go to controller. Ideally, the model should be bound to 'e' variable and name textbox value should be assigned to 'Name' variable.

Are similar names are not allowed in MVC models?

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive. Your code would be throwing a _An item with the same key has already been added_ exception because you have properties `Name` and `name`

Comment: Ohh. Thanks for the answer. Can we see that error somewhere? It is not throwing any exception.

Comment: It is throwing an exception, and you should be see the 'yellow screen of death' as soon as you hit the submit button (unless you handling exceptions and redirecting elsewhere)

Comment: Yeah. Now I can see. Actually I enabled Remote validation and imported js files for validation which was preventing the error screen to come. Thanks a lot